# I want to implement a simple update in my db but I am getting this { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 } in my console?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

#  I can't update keep getting { ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 } ! #
      ...
        const mongoose = require('mongoose');
        mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/mongo-exercises', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true })
        ...
            .then(() => console.log('Connected to MongoDB... '))
            .catch(() => console.error('Could not connect to MongoDB...', err));

```
...

    const courseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        tags: [String],
        date: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
        name: String,
        isPublished: Boolean,
        author: String,
        Price: Number
    ...
    });
    ...


 const Course = mongoose.model('Course', courseSchema);

 async function updateCourse(id){
    const result = await Course.updateOne({_id: id}, {
        $set: {
            author: 'Momo',
            isPublished: true
        }
    });
...

    console.log(result);    //{ n: 0, nModified: 0, ok: 1 }

}

...

 updateCourse('5a68ff090c553064a218a547');
```

> Blockquote

Comment: If you're using Postmon to send requests, make sure to choose `JSON` in the `Body`. The default `Text` wouldn't work and will give out this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it.. I did import the data to my database from a json file and the id didn't have an ObjectId and that doesn't work with the newer version of mongoose.

so the id was like this: **"_id":"5a68fdc3615eda645bc6bdec"**

and this the **right** way for mongoose 5.9.18 : "_id": **ObjectId**("5a68fdc3615eda645bc6bdec")

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one.

```
const result = await Course.updateOne({_id: id}, {
        $set: {
            author: 'Momo',
            isPublished: true
        },
      {new:true}
    }).lean();
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
async function connectDatabase() {
    try {
        await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/newdb21', {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useCreateIndex: true
          }).then(console.log('successfully connected to MongoDb'));
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('Could not connect to the database');
    }
}
connectDatabase();
    
// define a schema to store data
const courseSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    price: Number,
    isPublised:{ type:Boolean, default:false},
    tags: [String],
    date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
    author: String
});

// create a mode for the course
const Course = mongoose.model('Course',courseSchema);
async function updateCourses(id) {
    try {
        const courses = await Course .findById(id);
        if (!courses) return;
        courses.set({name:'nedu BOss'})
        courses.save();
        console.log(courses);
    } catch(err) {
        console.log('Couldnt update any item in the mongo database');
    }
}
    
//updateCourses('45563664345677');
// if the data was imported from another database you will experience the earlier issue
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
[{ 
 "_id": { 
  "$oid": "5a68fdc3615eda645bc6bdec" 
 }, 
 "tags": ["express", "backend"], 
 "date": "2018-01-24T21:42:27.388Z", 
 "name": "Express.js Course", 
 "author": "Mosh", 
 "isPublished": true 
}]
```

put your json data in this format